# How to create course work for a Google Classroom project using API in php

Tags: php, oauth, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-classroom

I want to create a course work(Assignment) as a course teacher using Google Classroom API to itself for a project in PHP. To create an assignment which correct code I wrote? Give me some suggestions with PHP code for creating an assignment.

I've added some code to the quickstart.php file.

**Code:**

```
$client = getClient();
        $courseId = '394192735087';
        $service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
        $post_body = new Google_Service_Classroom_CourseWork(array(
          'workType' => 'ASSIGNMENT',
          'title' => 'Quiz-5',
          'description' => 'where you add up by the number of numbers',
          'state' => 'PUBLISHED',
          'maxPoints' => 100,
          'associatedWithDeveloper' => true,
          'assigneeMode' => 'ALL_STUDENTS',
          'submissionModificationMode' => 'SUBMISSION_MODIFICATION_MODE_UNSPECIFIED'
          ));

        $service->courses_courseWork->create($courseId, $post_body);
```

**But when I run this code in quickstart.php at localhost the following problems can be seen.**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"name\" at 'course_
work': Cannot find field.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"name\" at 'cou
rse_work': Cannot find field.",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\REST.php:128
```

**How can I solved it ?**

Comment: @DaImTo  I have updated my question. Now, How can I fix the problem?

Comment: @DaImTo  Thank you so much for giving valuable suggestions.  Now this problem is fully fixed.